# "show removed posts" checkbox not working (under Reputation)

Tags: support, profile-page

When I go to [the "Reputation" tab for my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1128875/jburace?tab=reputation) and click the "show removed posts" checkbox, the page suddenly jumps to this raw HTML/JS:

[image]

And it stays there, infinitely loading. This happens on Chrome 18.0.1025.151 m and Firefox 8.0.1, with no extensions/addons.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I am behind a proxy, but none of SE is blocked.

Maybe there's some funky cross-domain AJAX going on here?

The JS console log shows nothing.

The Network tab on the Chrome developer tool showed 1 GET and no errors. The response of the GET:

```
    "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "statusText": "OK",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/0.9",
      "headers": [],
      "cookies": [],
      "content": {
        "size": 30614,
        "mimeType": "text/plain"
      },
      "redirectURL": "",
      "headersSize": 19,
      "bodySize": 0
    },
```

Comment: No repro on Chrome latest.

Comment: At a glance, I think you have a crazy proxy between you and us...any idea if that's the case?

Comment: I am indeed behind an organization proxy, but none of SE is blocked. Strange.

Comment: Norepro Chrome Canary

Comment: @JBurace: Maybe the filtering regex decided that it doesn't like headers? Strange though.

Comment: Does this work when not behind that proxy?  This has been reported nowhere else...I do believe the proxy you're behind isn't setup correctly.

Comment: To notify people of comment reply please use `@` for example adding `@Nick` in the beginning will notify him of your comment, otherwise he will most likely miss it.

Comment: @NickCraver It does outside the proxy, at a friends place etc. Everything else (Google, Bing, etc) work just fine under the proxy so everything looks fine. Not sure how it wouldn't be setup right and cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this happens, go to the Network tab of Chrome developer tools:

[image: chrome network tab]

And you will hopefully see something abnormal like error status that will shed some light on what exactly is being blocked.

Comment: I tried that and only saw 1 method "GET", which looked fine. See my post for the response of the GET.

Comment: Looks like mime type issue - should be text/html not text/plain.

Comment: Good point. I checked some other SE functions like "flag" and it returns text/html. Is SE sending it as text/plain, or is something on my end interfering and changing that?

Comment: Your end otherwise we would have seen influx of reports...